# How can I make an array to show clicks made over a whole datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, click

The pourpose is to build a 3xn array (3 columns,n rows),which shows/enumerate the clicks made all over the datagriview.

3 Columns Column1: number of click, first click all over the datagridview. Column2: e.columnindex of the click all over the datagridview. Column3: e.rowindex of the click all over the datagridview.

n rows: Row 1: info related to first click made all over the dgv, i.e.: (1,3,7) (click 1, columnindex of the click 3, rowindex of the click 7) .... Row n; total number of clicks made over the dgv.

Here the best code I have:

```
Private Accums As New ArrayList
Private Sub ClickMouse(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles datagridview.CellMouseClick
Accums.Add(New Integer() {e.Clicks, e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex})
End Sub
```

Comment: So each click anywhere in the grid adds a new row? Do you want to distinguish single and double clicks?

Comment: Each click anywhere adds a new row (not in the datagrid, I mean in the matrix/array). I dont want to distinguish single and double clicks, I want to focus only on single clicks. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should create the structure as required (if there is no error :D):

```
Dim ClikAr(2,-1) As Integer '-1 is described in MSDN. I have never tried it.

Private Sub ClickMouse(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles datagridview.CellMouseClick
   Dim ClickNum As Integer = Ubound(ClickAr,2)+1
   Redim Preserve ClickAr(2,ClickNum)
   ClickAr(0,ClickNum) = ClickNum
   ClickAr(1,ClickNum) = e.ColumnIndex
   ClickAr(2,ClickNum) = e.RowIndex

   'e.Clicks can be used to distinguish Double Clicks.  
End Sub
```

The problem of this solution is that on **each click** the array is recreated and values are copied into, which is not very efficient. You can create a large array beforehand but this is not very efficient too. By my opinion the original solution is better. I have modified is slightly to be closer to required structure but the first item in array is not necessary because it an index or the ArrayList

```
Private Accums As New ArrayList
Private Sub ClickMouse(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles datagridview.CellMouseClick
   Accums.Add(New Integer() {Accums.Count, e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex})
End Sub
```

I both cases I am using the number of created "records" as counter. If separate counter is more convenient it can be declared on Class level and incremented in the event procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to handle the `DataGridView`'s [CellClicked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx) event and extract the `ColumnIndex` and `RowIndex` properties from the [DataGridViewCellEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.aspx) parameter it provides.  The rest after that should be a simple matter of creating a new row (if necessary) and populating the appropriate values.

Comment: Hi Adrian! Thank you for your effort but I have tried to do this but is does not work.

Comment: What happens when you try it?  Can you share the code you've written in an edit to your question?